# Async computed in vue

Tags: vuejs3, loading

This is my code. button loading is not working. I am trying to when call api then I want to show loader in button but here v-if is not working as well. When I am calling the api it will true but not again false.  I am getting error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7TNK.png)

```
   <template>
   <Layout>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3">
        <div></div>
        <div class="my-20 border-2 rounded-md p-5 bg-white">
            <h5 class="text-center mb-5 text-3xl">Forget password</h5>
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="mb-2 font-bold"><label>Email</label></div>
                <input type="email" class="w-full border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg p-2 px-4"
                    placeholder="e. g. john@example.com" v-model="email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button type="primary" :onclick="handleSubmit" :disabled="disabled" 
        class="w-full btn-class">
                    <i v-if="loading" class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2"></i>Send Email
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <router-link to="/signin" class="text-blue-500 hover:underline ml-3">
                    Go Back
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </Layout>
  </template>


  <script setup>

 import { computed, ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
  import { useAuthStore } from '../store'
  import { Layout } from '../components/Layout';

 const userStore = useAuthStore();
 const loading = computed(() => userStore.loading)

 const email = ref('')
 const disabled = computed(() => !email.value);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  await userStore.forgetPassword({ email: email.value });
 }

 </script>
```

I have tried with nextTick(), and computed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add the spinner only after clicking the button. Then, remove the spinner after the async function finishes.

IMHO, the loading is not set back to false. I would suggest:

```
const loading = ref(false);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  loading.value = true;
  try {
    await userStore.forgetPassword({ email: email.value });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
  loading.value = false;
}
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: there is an error in forgetPassword function. The loading.value is never set back to false because when forgetPassword fails, the rest of the code is not executed. You should check/share forgetPassword function I guess.

Comment: I found the issue. fontawesome <i> tag need to wrap by span or div then its worked and also need to use try catch

Comment: if this solved the issue, I would appreciate it if you upvote/accept this as an answer.